# Any definitions of the word "ask" as an adjective, possibly dialect and possibly meaning astringent?

Tags: adjectives, dialects

Title says it all probably.

Does anyone have any recollections of this usage?

Any definitions of the word "ask" as an adjective, possibly dialect and possibly meaning astringent?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you'd use this word?  I'm having a hard time imagining the word "ask" used as an adjective...

Comment: The only form of `ask` that is an adjective, to my knowledge, is **unasking**. But it does not share the same definition as **astringent**.

Comment: Can you fill us in a bit on why you are asking? If we can understand what has prompted the query it might put us on the right track.

Comment: I have a vague memory of it being used in my childhood, as in "that drink/food was a bit ask". Possibly Lancashire or Yorkshire dialect?

Comment: Ask and tha' shall get, lad. or something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Ask**](https://archive.org/stream/glossaryoflancas00nodauoft/glossaryoflancas00nodauoft_djvu.txt)

> **ASK**, adj. hard, dry.  *Icel. heskr, hastr, harsh.*
>
> COLL. USE. x . it's an ask wind this mornin.
>
> 2. This ale has an asky taste.

*A Glossary of the Lancashire dialect*

Comment: Nifty! What's the source?

Comment: The link goes to *A glossary of the Lancashire dialect*.

Comment: This isn't the first time I've come across Icelandic and Lanky associations.

Comment: By the way, "A glossary of the Lancashire dialect" does not appear in the "commonly-available references" referred to in the "put on hold as off-topic" comment above. The quote from it answers my question, thanks.